# What does this "striping" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, terminology

> Compute Engine manages the hardware behind persistent disks so you can
>   add and resize your disks without handling striping or redundancy.

What does this "striping" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a computer technology niche term that only has a suggestive relationship to the English word.

Margaret Rouse discusses this in a Search Storage article on [**disk striping**](https://searchstorage.techtarget.com/definition/disk-striping):

> Disk striping is the process of dividing a body of data into blocks and spreading the data blocks across multiple storage devices, such as hard disks or solid-state drives (SSDs). A stripe consists of the data divided across the set of hard disks or SSDs, and a striped unit, or strip, that refers to the data slice on an individual drive.

Laying down data across disks is suggestive of the kind of striping pattern that a whip might make, or the stripes of a zebra.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most helpful resources on the web is OneLook, which looks up words in several dictionaries, including technical dictionaries.

When I looked up *striping* on [OneLook](https://onelook.com/?w=striping&ls=a), it returned three hits from computing dictionaries. One of those entries reads:

> **[data striping](http://foldoc.org/striping)**
>
> <sup>(storage)</sup>
>
> Segmentation of logically sequential data, such as a single file, so that segments can be written to multiple physical devices (usually disk drives) in a round-robin fashion. This technique is useful if the processor is capable of reading or writing data faster than a single disk can supply or accept it. While data is being transferred from the first disk, the second disk can locate the next segment.

Whatever it means in the Compute Engine marketing materials, it sounds like their company has something (probably software) that makes it easier for end users to store data.